# system-config.js fails after adding service with angular-cli

Tags: angular-cli

```
  $ ng --version
  angular-cli: 1.0.0-beta.10
  node: 5.10.1
  os: win32 ia32
```

- 'ng new' works
- 'ng serve' works
- modifying app.component works
- 'ng g service my-service' works
- import my-service in app.component/adding to contructor for injection) does not work (see error output below)
- remove service import from app.component - does not work, neither (see error output below)

After it fails it never work again. Even if I rollback to the generated code.

Error output in firebug console:

```
Error: @http://localhost:4200/system-config.js:34:5
Call@http://localhost:4200/vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js:289:14
forEach@http://localhost:4200/vendor/es6-shim/es6-shim.js:1295:14
@http://localhost:4200/system-config.js:33:1
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:323:20
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.run@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:216:25
scheduleResolveOrReject/<@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:571:53
Zone</ZoneDelegate</ZoneDelegate.prototype.invokeTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:356:24
Zone</Zone</Zone.prototype.runTask@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:256:29
drainMicroTaskQueue@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:474:26
ZoneTask/this.invoke@http://localhost:4200/vendor/zone.js/dist/zone.js:426:22

Evaluating http://localhost:4200/system-config.js
Error loading http://localhost:4200/system-config.js
```

Comment: Same issue here. For me it simply doesnt work even I didnt make any change. Just stop the server once and start and I see this error message. So basically 1) ng new my-app --> 2) cd my-app --> 3) ng serve --> 4) Open browser and open http://localhost:4200/ --> 5) Can see app with text app works! --> 6) Stop server (ctrl + c) --> 7) ng serve
    #. Boom!!!, it does't work. 

Getting the error as mentioned by @czinkos

Comment: Btw did you try this with Chrome browser? For me it works, but have issue with Firefox.

Comment: I also had the same issue. I restarted firefox and it worked again. A Shift-F5 did not work. Stumped me for ages.

Comment: angular-cli has moved to webpack. After switching to webpack version (the master branch now), it works fine.

Answer (score 0):

angular-cli has moved to webpack. After switching to webpack version (the master branch now), it works fine.

see: https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1417